# Why am I unable to add a field to a hosted feature service in ArcGIS Enterprise?

Tags: arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, arcgis-enterprise, schema-locks

I have a hosted feature service that I published from ArcGIS Pro to Enterprise. This layer is updated via a model I run once a quarter and is used in a dashboard. I want to add a new text field to the hosted feature service. There's been a lot of arcade coding in the popups and dashboard and I'm hesitated to republish the feature service and start the dashboard over. I'm wondering if anyone might have any ideas as to why I'm encountering this issue and potential advice for a workaround/solution.

I've tried (and failed) a few different things to be able to add the field. I'll list them below.

- In Server Administrator I stopped the service and attempted to add the field both in Pro and Enterprise.
- Again in Server Administrator I stopped and then started the service and attempted to add the field.
- I looked in Server Manager to get any more information and am unable to get any information about if the database schema is locked. I'll include a picture attachment. In other services, that are not hosted feature services, I can see options for Parameters, Capabilities, Pooling, Processes, Caching, and Item Description. Not sure if this is helpful information here.

[image: Hosted Feature Service in Server Manager]

Comment: I think republishing might be the only way. Results on ESRI community forums suggest this too.

Comment: Are you saying you've tried the Add Field tool inside ArcGIS Pro and it fails? If so, what is the error? Which version of ArcGIS Enterprise? Have you tried adding a field from the Portal home app data tab of the actual feature service item?

Comment: Changing the schema of a published service requires republishing the service.